# how to skip or call another model's hook in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hook

I have a logic like this:

```
# SomeModel
before_save :before_save_callback
def before_save_callback
  AnotherModel.find(..).update!(name: 'random text')
end

# AnotherModel
before_save :before_save_callback
def before_save_callback
  self.assign_attributes(name: 'random text')
end
```

There are 2 triggers that do the same update. However, if I do it like this, and update SomeModel, it will do the update 2x (before_save_callback in SomeModel and before_save_callback in AnotherModel). Is there a way where I can skip callback without using update_column as I only want to ignore this specific callback? Or maybe can I trigger before_save_callback of AnotherModel in SomeModel without actually saving any attributes? Thanks

Comment: Or just maybe callbacks are not the right answer for whatever it is you're doing? https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/cqci3i/callbacks_good_bad_or_ugly/

Comment: @max thx for the interesting link. do u have any suggestion of alternatives that i can use?

Comment: The Service Object pattern is often used instead of callbacks. The important thing really is to use explicit logic instead of of implicit when you have complex interactions between different models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around model callbacks with transient attributes:

```rb
# AnotherModel
attr_accessible :skip_some_callback
before_save :before_save_callback, unless: :skip_some_callback
# ...

# SomeModel
def before_save_callback
  AnotherModel.find(..).update!(skip_some_callback: true, name: 'random text')
end
```

But this pattern can quickly turn into a callback hell and for complex cases you can better organize your code into more high-level patterns like service objects, interactors, factories etc.